# Trouble Using API in Django

Tags: python, django-models

```
class CityData(models.Model):
    cityname = CharField(max_length = 200, null = True, blank = True)
    citystate = CharField(max_length = 200, null = True, blank = True)
    
    @property
    def cities_url(self):
        return f"https://wft-geo-db.p.rapidapi.com/v1/geo/countries/US/regions/{self.citystate}/cities"
   
    @property
    def cities_querystring(self):
        return {"namePrefix": self.cityname}
    cities_headers = {
        'x-rapidapi-key': "",
        'x-rapidapi-host': "wft-geo-db.p.rapidapi.com"
        }

    @property
    def city_response(self):
        self.response = requests.request("GET", self.cities_url, headers = self.cities_headers, params = self.cities_querystring)
        self.response = self.response.json()
        return self.response["data"][0]

    @property
    def city_latitude(self):
        return self.city_response["latitude"]
    @property
    def city_longitude(self):
        return self.city_response["longitude"]
```

I keep getting an error:

> KeyError at /admin/Weather/citydata/ 'data'

I am trying to make the app get city data by typing in the city name and state name into the admin new CityData.
For example:
[image]

_________________________**********************Edit**********************

would return Seattle, WA's latitude and longitude.

The data looks like this after `response.json()` in a different program I have that does not use Django.

> {'data': [{'id': 127352, 'wikiDataId': 'Q466190', 'type': 'CITY',
> 'city': 'Great Falls', 'name': 'Great Falls', 'latitude':
> 47.503611111, 'longitude': -111.286388888, 'population': 58505}], 'metadata': {'currentOffset': 0, 'totalCount': 1}}

______________________________*****************Edit*****************

I finally managed to figure out that having

```
@property
def city_latitude(self):
    return self.city_response["latitude"]
@property
def city_longitude(self):
    return self.city_response["longitude"]
```

with one calling the same API right after the other, I was going over my calls/second limit. Any ideas on how to work around this without slowing down the loading time for the page?

Comment: The likely cause is that `self.response` does not contain a top-level key named `"data"`.

Comment: Could you tell me how to get a top-level key for "data"? I have tried changing different parts to strings since I saw it was a "property type" that is different than the successful programs I have had with the API outside of Django.

Comment: Update the question to show the contents of `self.response`.

Comment: That does contain a top-level key named `"data"`, so the response must be different.

Comment: Try to use [`cache_property`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/utils/#django.utils.functional.cached_property) on `self.city_response`